# vbscript compare string contents (folder directory) of text files and creates the missing folders

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am currently working on a school assignment to compare strings within text files. These text files contains paths of folder directories. If a directory is not found on the other textfile, it will create that directory, else nothing will happen.

diretory1.txt contains directory strings that are:

```
C:\mcgfiles\avp
C:\mcgfiles\temp
C:\mcgfiles\logs\activity
C:\mcgfiles\logs\program
C:\mcgfiles\logs\status
C:\mcgfiles\generatedhtml
```

and diretory2.txt, contains the following

```
C:\mcgfiles
C:\mcgfiles\avp
C:\mcgfiles\temp
C:\mcgfiles\logs
C:\mcgfiles\logs\activity
C:\mcgfiles\logs\program
C:\mcgfiles\logs\status
C:\mcgfiles\generatedhtml
```

In the case of my textfiles, directories "C:\mcgfiles" and "C:\mcgfiles\logs" will be created on my drive C:\ since they are missing.

Here is the code I used:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\scripts\directory1.txt", ForReading)
strAddresses = objFile1.ReadAll
objFile1.Close
Set objFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\scripts\directory2.txt", ForReading)
Do Until objFile2.AtEndOfStream
    strCurrent = objFile2.ReadLine
    If InStr(strAddresses, strCurrent) = 0 Then
        objFSO.CreateFolder(strCurrent)
    End If
Loop
```

It works fine when I use "C:\mcgfiles\temp" as the missing directory. But it cant differentiate what's missing when I use "C:\mcgfiles" or "C:\mcgfiles\logs". Maybe its because I used InStr function and it considers "C:\mcgfiles" and "C:\mcgfiles\logs" not missing since it can also be found in "C:\mcgfiles\logs\activity" etc.
I tried to use strComp but still nothing happens. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[InStr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) "returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another". So "C:\mcgfiles" is found in "C:\mcgfiles\logs". If all of the pathes in the string you search in are terminated by an EOL marker (eg.g vbCrLf) you can use `target & EOL` as the needle:

```
>> haystack = "c:\a\b;c:\a;"
>> eol = ";"
>> needle = "c:\a" & eol
>> WScript.Echo InStr(haystack, needle)
>>
8
```

Other techniques - e.g. using a dictionary of the pathes - are possible, but would need more work.

Comment: how about using strcomp()?